# trying to implement a back button but keep getting a crash

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, modalviewcontroller

trying to run the code but it crashes or terminates with a SIGABRT message in the debug console

```
- (IBAction)backButtonPushed:(id)sender {

    ViewController *backView = [backView initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    backView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:backView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did you modally switch to the view you are now trying to dismiss?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do with this line of code, but it's wrong regardless:

```
ViewController *backView = [backView initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
```

Your crash is most likely due to that line from the standpoint that backView is nil (for which the crash would be two lines later when you try to present it as a modal view controller), or is really some other object under the covers because it's never properly initialized.

What you really need to do is something along the lines of (assuming you have a corresponding interface file, aka "nib"):

```
ViewController *backView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"<your controller's nib name here>" bundle:NULL];
```

Or if you are totally creating ViewController programmatically, then use:

```
ViewController *backView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

Or whatever initialization method you have defined.

Comment: Right, although I would like to mention that sending messages to nil doesn't do anything (eg. it doesn't crash!). So its also possible that the crash happens on `[self presentModalViewController:backView animated:YES];` because of an unhandled expection.

Comment: for some reason when I try to use the alloc method it doesn't show up or recognize at all... and gives me a warning... and by the way I am using ARC...